# Logic for starting a thread of posts using MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I decided to build my own social network from the ground up because I realized it would be an interesting exercise and I didn't want to spend a lot of time learning to customize an out-of-the-box solution like Drupal Commons. I've done well so far with things like basic login/logout functionality, creating a new user, uploading an avatar, etc. I also have a MySQL database table that holds posts by users.

Running basic queries on the `posts` table I can easily retrieve a post, its ID, and the user that created it (userID is a foreign key from the `users` table). However, I decided I wanted to implement a `threads` table with a `threadID`. This way, posts can be sorted not only according to their date or postID, but by topic.

I'm unsure of the logic for posting a new thread, however. My database consists of the following tables: Users, Posts, Threads. In the database, they are structured like this (only relevant fields shown):

```
Users         Posts         Threads
-----         -----         -------
userID (pk)   postID (pk)   threadID (pk)
              userID (fk)  
              threadID (fk)
```

*The above formatting looks OK in the preview, I apologize if it goes totally wonky after I post*

User creation is separate from post creation, therefore I already have a `userID` created and available when I make a new post. Then the post auto-generates its own postID. What is stopping me from moving forward is that I am not quite sure how to create a new `threadID` **and** `postID` in the same transaction to ensure that they are properly aware of each other. The only time I would need a new threadID is if someone was, well, starting a new thread. Replies would use the existing threadID and get a unique postID.

If anyone can shed some light on the basic logic of this transaction I would really appreciate it. I haven't worked much with relational databases in the past so this is an opportunity to learn something useful, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is to change the threadID to parentID, which then refers to either another postID if it's a child in a thread or -1 (or 0) when it's a normal parent post. This way you can thread any post with ease, and you don't even need a Threads table. Let me know if this makes sense to you :)

Comment: This method also has a second benefit: this way, replies can be nested, otherwise you could only reply to the original message. Therefore, +1!

Comment: You mean change `threadID` from a FK in the `posts`  table to be `parentID` where it inherits another `postID`?

Comment: @armadadrive yes, that is what I mean. And whenever it doesn't inherit anything, you can leave it null, 0, or -1, then base your logic around that. So to get all parent posts, you could make the query `Select * From Posts Where parentID=-1`, and then for each of those, load their children.

Comment: I like it! It's clean and flexible. Thanks!